# How to get legend when using different lines with `geom_line()` and indicating specific colours outside `aes()`?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting four columns versus time in a plot. Each one of these columns is plotted as a different `Y` variable, while time is in the `X` axes. Below I share a fake-example dataframe:

```
  df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2020-08-05","2020-08-06","2020-08-07","2020-08-08","2020-08-09","2020-08-10","2020-08-11","2020-08-12")),
                   State.1_day=c(0.8,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.7),
                   State.2_day=c(0.4,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6),
                   State.1_night=c(0.7,0.8,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.3,0.2),
                   State.2_night=c(0.5,0.6,0.7,0.4,0.3,0.5,0.6,0.7))
  
  df

        date State.1_day State.2_day State.1_night State.2_night
1 2020-08-05         0.8         0.4           0.7           0.5
2 2020-08-06         0.3         0.2           0.8           0.6
3 2020-08-07         0.2         0.1           0.5           0.7
4 2020-08-08         0.5         0.2           0.4           0.4
5 2020-08-09         0.6         0.3           0.3           0.3
6 2020-08-10         0.7         0.4           0.2           0.5
7 2020-08-11         0.8         0.5           0.3           0.6
8 2020-08-12         0.7         0.6           0.2           0.7

library(RColorBrewer)

line_colors_a <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(6, "Blues")[c(3,6)]
  line_colors_a
  
  line_colors_b <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(6, "Greens")[c(3,6)]
  line_colors_b
  
  line_colors <- c(line_colors_a,line_colors_b)

 Plot <- ggplot() +
    geom_line(data=df,aes(y = State.1_day, x=date), colour = line_colors[1] ,size=1) +
    geom_line(data=df,aes(y = State.1_night, x=date), colour = line_colors[2],size=1) +
    geom_line(data=df,aes(y = State.2_day, x=date), colour = line_colors[3],size=1) +
    geom_line(data=df,aes(y = State.2_night, x=date), colour = line_colors[4],size=1) +
    scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d")) +
    scale_color_discrete(name = "States", labels = c("Active_day", "Active_night", "Resting_day", "Resting_night")) +
    theme_bw() +
    labs(y = "% time", x = "Date") +
    theme(strip.text = element_text(face="bold", size=18),
          strip.background=element_rect(fill="white", colour="black",size=2),
          axis.title.x =element_text(margin = margin(t = 10, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0),size = 20),
          axis.title.y =element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0),size = 20),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 70, hjust = 1,size = 15),
          axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5,size = 15),
          axis.line = element_line(),
          panel.grid.major= element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          legend.text=element_text(size=18),
          legend.title = element_text(size=19, face = "bold"),
          legend.key=element_blank(),
          legend.position = "top",
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          strip.placement = "outside")
  Plot
```

[image]

I am pretty close to what I need, however, I don't get that the legend is shown in the plot. I use the argument `colour` outside of `aes()` because if I use it within `aes()`, the colours are not those that I want. I tried to get it using `scale_color_discrete()`, however, I do not get any legend.

How could I get a legend indicating to which variable correspond each one of those lines?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

To address both the legend and palette issue at the same time. First you could convert the data frame into long format using `pivot_longer()`, then add a column that specifies the colour you want with the associated variable. You can map those colours using `scale_colour_manual()`. Not the most elegant solution but I found it useful when dealing with manually set palettes.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2020-08-05","2020-08-06","2020-08-07","2020-08-08","2020-08-09","2020-08-10","2020-08-11","2020-08-12")),
                 State.1_day=c(0.8,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.7),
                 State.2_day=c(0.4,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6),
                 State.1_night=c(0.7,0.8,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.3,0.2),
                 State.2_night=c(0.5,0.6,0.7,0.4,0.3,0.5,0.6,0.7))

line_colors_a <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(6, "Blues")[c(3,6)]
line_colors_a

line_colors_b <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(6, "Greens")[c(3,6)]
line_colors_b

line_colors <- c(line_colors_a,line_colors_b)

df1 <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-date) %>% 
  mutate(colour = case_when(
    name == "State.1_day" ~ line_colors[1],
    name == "State.1_night" ~ line_colors[2],
    name == "State.2_day" ~ line_colors[3],
    name == "State.2_night" ~ line_colors[4]
  ))

ggplot(df1, aes(x = date, y = value, colour = name)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y-%m-%d") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = tibble::deframe(distinct(df1, colour, name))) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(y = "% time", x = "Date") +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(face="bold", size=18),
        strip.background=element_rect(fill="white", colour="black",size=2),
        axis.title.x =element_text(margin = margin(t = 10, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0),size = 20),
        axis.title.y =element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0),size = 20),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 70, hjust = 1,size = 15),
        axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5,size = 15),
        axis.line = element_line(),
        panel.grid.major= element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.text=element_text(size=18),
        legend.title = element_text(size=19, face = "bold"),
        legend.key=element_blank(),
        legend.position = "top",
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @EJJ. Just an extra-dobut, do you know how to change the names in the legend? Both the title and the text. Using your approach I wonder how to get that.

Comment: You can pass `name` and `labels` in `scale_colour_manual()` to specify the name/title of the legend and labels/text used

Comment: Thanks @EJJ. Something strange happens. I have copied your code and I have run it, and I got a plot without lines. It is empty. There is a warning message saying that `Removed 32 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path)`. Have you used the same code that you shared?

Answer (score 0):

Since @EJJ's reply did not work for some reason, I used a similar approach but using `melt()`. Here is the code and the plot:

```
  colnames(df) <- c("date","Act_day","Rest_day","Act_night","Rest_night")
  df <- melt(df, id.vars=c("date"))
  colnames(df) <- c("date","State","value")
  
  Plot <- ggplot(df,aes(x = date, y = value, colour = State)) +
    geom_line(size = 1) +
    scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d")) +
    scale_color_discrete(name = "States", labels = c("Active_day", "Active_night", "Resting_day", "Resting_night")) +
    theme_bw() +
    labs(y = "% time", x = "Date") +
    theme(strip.text = element_text(face="bold", size=18),
          strip.background=element_rect(fill="white", colour="black",size=2),
          axis.title.x =element_text(margin = margin(t = 10, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0),size = 20),
          axis.title.y =element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0),size = 20),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 70, hjust = 1,size = 15),
          axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5,size = 15),
          axis.line = element_line(),
          panel.grid.major= element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          legend.text=element_text(size=18),
          legend.title = element_text(size=19, face = "bold"),
          legend.key=element_blank(),
          legend.position = "top",
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          strip.placement = "outside") +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("Act_day" = line_colors[1], "Act_night" = line_colors[2], "Rest_day" = line_colors[3], "Rest_night" = line_colors[4]))
  
  Plot
```

[image]